# macOS App That Shows Connected Bluetooth Devices in Menu Bar

Tags: macos, bluetooth, menu-bar

Apple changed their bluetooth menu bar icon in recent years so its impossible to tell if any and what devices are actually connected without tapping to open up the menu. This sucks. I'd love to be able to see that my bluetooth headphones, or mouse, etc are connected at a glance, without additional effort. Anyone aware of any way to achieve this, perhaps with additional app which shows status in the menu bar? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [ToothFairy](https://c-command.com/toothfairy/). It shows icons of Bluetooth devices that indicate connectivity status.